# Что такое Anaconda для Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

Что такое [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/) ?

- Какие задачи она позволяет решать, и почему нельзя без нее обойтись?
- Стоит ли её ставить новичку параллельно с установленными Python`ами 32 + 64.
  Чем она может помочь? Если можно на доступном языке для совсем начинающего.

Comment: Если Вы решили начать изучать питон, то оно Вам скорее всего не нужно.

> почему нельзя без нее обойтись?

можно, она не нужна начинающему питонисту.

Comment: А что она из себя представляет, пробовал найти информацию в ютубе, гугле но не получилось. Единственное что увидел это какой то онлайн блокнот\Shell в браузере.

Comment: у них на сайте все подробно описано и есть курсы. Читайте/смотрите.

Comment: @KoVadim У меня был мега адский головняк с установкой ряда библиотек под Windows. Убил на это весь день. В итоге проблема решилась за 10 минут установкой Анаконды. Почему люди на форумах\подобных сайтах написать в "общих" словах и направить "читать\учить". Вы поймите вот ваш ответ еще 100 человек или 1000 может посмотреть за год-два. Чем больше "сопротивление" тем больше будет таких вопросов и наоборот. Не все знают английский и переваривают пафосные описания в "Общих" словах как на сайте анаконды. Написали бы так: Анаконда-это питон с 350-450 установленными пакетами\библиотеками.

Answer (score 19):

В моем представлении новичка:

Anaсonda это:

- Включает предустановленный Python 2.7 , 3.4. 3.5
- +-150 предустановленных библиотек, и более 200-300 готовых к "легкой" установке библиотек командой conda install name_lib
- Включает в себя IDLE Spider 2

В каких случаях я нашел применение для себя:
Писал код на Ubuntu, там с установкой библиотек не было проблем. Решив скомпилировать под Windows, начал устанавливать библиотеки и естественно натыкался на все камни\грабли. В отличии от Ubuntu в Windows  приходится просто ужасно. Установив Anaconda я с легкостью запустил весь код написанный на Ubuntu, доставив одной-двумя командами недостающие библиотеки (через Anaconda prompt). Поэтому думаю новичкам Анаконда очень пригодиться, и сэкономит вам пару дней жизни.

[Список поддерживаемых пакетов (библиотек) и их версии](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs).
При этом учтите, что там по порядку идут 3 версии от Python 2.7 - 3.5).

[Установка Анаконды](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install).

Comment: а как же pip install?

Comment: а что с пипом?) работает илм вы о проблемных библиотеках под виндой?

Comment: pip вроде бы справляется, чем anaсonda лучше?

Comment: pip в анаконде да. а без  анаконды на питоне я мучался с установкой библиотек

Comment: @gil9red : `conda` полезна, если нет бинарной wheel  сборки под Windows, когда пакет использует C расширения (так как `pip install` заставляет компилировать локально в этом случае, что может быть не удобно на Винде).

Comment: @jfs, я обычно бинарные сборки, которых нет в `pip` ищу [тут](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs)

Comment: @gil9red: Я говорю о случаях, когда *"нет бинарной wheel сборки под Windows"*. [Gohlke архив](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs)  как раз и предоставляет бинарные wheels для многих популярных пакетов (обратите внимание на `.whl` расширение). Другими словами я говорю о пакетах, которых там нет.

Answer (score 18):

Pip - стандартный менеджер пакетов питона, позволяет устанавливать бинарные wheel сборки пакетов. Если их нет (ни в самом Pip, ни где-то еще), Pip компилирует пакеты локально. При этом могут возникнуть проблемы при сложных зависимостях, когда требуются сторонние не питон библиотеки. В этом случае удобно использовать Conda.

Команды Pip:

- pip search package_name - поиск пакета через pip
- pip install package_name - установка пакета через pip

Conda - менеджер пакетов питона, позволяет устанавливать уже скомпилированные пакеты (может работать и в режиме компиляции пакетов перед установкой). Также Conda - менеджер окружений системы, позволяет создавать окружения с разными версиями чего угодно (библиотеки C, низкоуровневые библиотеки и т.д.).

Conda бывает в двух версиях:

- Анаконда - более 150 предустановленных пакетов (около 3 Гб) + более 250 пакетов, готовых к установке командой conda install package_name
- Миниконда - более 400 пакетов, готовых к установке командой conda install package_name

и Анаконда и Миниконда включают:

- conda
- интерпретатор питона
- pip

Команды Conda:

- conda search package_name - поиск пакета через conda
- conda install package_name - установка пакета через conda
- conda install - установка всего стандартного набора пакетов - более 150, около 3 Гб
- conda list - список установленных пакетов
- conda update conda - обновление conda
- conda clean -t - удаление кеша - архивов .tar.bz2, которые могут занимать много места и не нужны

Comment: @jfs, благодарю за замечания. Исправил неточности.

Comment: *"Pip - менеджер окружений питона"* откуда вы подобные утверждения берёте (серьёзно, нужно issue открыть, чтобы поправили). Pip работает с Питон пакетами (из разных мест может ставить). Фраза "окружения Питона" обычно  к virtualenv относится. Вы с conda  командой путаете, которая и пакеты может ставить, и окружениями управлять и даже версиями самого Питона управлять. 2- [опционально] про сложные зависимости: если имеются ввиду, что Питон пакеты могут требовать для работы установку сторонних (не Питон)  библиотек, то в таких случаях системный package manager можно использовать, к примеру apt.

Comment: @jfs, 2. Да, это имелось ввиду. Без conda можно обойтись, но, в частности, на винде не очень удобно компилировать локально пакеты, которым нужны для работы не питон библиотеки.

Comment: @jfs, pip (начиная с python 3.4) и venv (начиная с python 3.3) идут в коробке с питоном. Имелось ввиду, что менеджер окружений venv идет одновременно с pip по дефолту, а conda предоставляет другой менеджер пакетов и менеджер окружений.

Comment: с Питоном много модулей поставляется. Не путайте venv и pip это разные вещи. venv и virtualenv похожие вещи, но также различные. Кстати, pip доступен и с python 2.7

Comment: @jfs, Вы самостоятельно удалили свой первый комментарий к данному ответу? Судя по комментарию stear386, он имел место быть. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных: если автор исправляет свой ответ в соответствии с моим замечанием и иначе оно не пригодится будущим читателям, то я стараюсь удалять такие комментарии.